# Swift 4: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle' for custom UITableViewCell (no IB)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have built my own UITableViewCell (entirely by code, no interface builder) and I'm getting the fallowing exception:

> [...] NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle [...]

Im fairly certain I don't need to use awakeFromNib() (see code) but this is the only way I got it working when passing it as "non-reusable"

```
// this works
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath [...] {
    return myCustomCell() 

// this fails
tableView.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "foo")
//throws immediately after this line: "[...] Could not load NIB in bundle"
```

My custom cell:

```
class TextValueTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let textField: UITextField = UITextField(
        frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 5, width: 350, height: 25)
    )
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 5, width: 350, height: 25))


    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.awakeFromNib();
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.label.text = "oh"
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.label)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.textField)
        self.textField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
        self.textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        self.textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.label.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.textField.textAlignment = .right;
        self.textField.placeholder = "Account Name"
    }



    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

}
```

As I said, I have not used the interface builder (and I'm not planing on it) so I'm not sure why it would try to load something from the bundle. Specifically, wouldn't I have to register it as a NIB then?

```
 tableView.register(<#T##nib: UINib?##UINib?#>, forCellReuseIdentifier: <#T##String#>)
```

Comment: Why do you call `awakeFromNib()` manually? It is a method for nib.

Comment: when i pass on my custom cell "return myCustomCell()" awakeFromNib() doesnt seem to get called -> But I might not be using this correctly :)

Comment: Remove the `awakeFromNib` func. Move the rest of that code to a "setup" func with the exception of the `super.awakeFromNib()` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TextValueTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let textField: UITextField = UITextField(
        frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 5, width: 350, height: 25)
    )

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 5, width: 350, height: 25))

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setupCell()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupCell()
    }

    func setupCell() {
        label.text = "oh"
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(textField)
        textField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        textField.textAlignment = .right;
        textField.placeholder = "Account Name"
    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you - did that but it's still throwing the same error. :(

Btw this seems to work:

Comment: Btw this seems to work: let testView  = UITableView();
testView.register(TextValueTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "foo") - so I believe it might have something to do with the way my UITableView is setup? (class UITableViewNavigation: UITableViewController { ... })

Answer (score 0):

For example If your using a UIViewController class name as TextPicker
Then u need to use like Bellow Code

```
      let bundle = Bundle(for: TextPicker.self)
      super.init(nibName: "TextPicker" , bundle: bundle)
```

If You are using TableView with Xib in other project as Framework

```
      tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "TextPickerCell", bundle: bundle), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextPickerCell")
  let bundle = Bundle(for: TextPicker.self)
```